# NumPy indexing with varying position

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have an array input_data of shape (A, B, C), and an array ind of shape (B,). I want to loop through the B axis and take the sum of elements C[B[i]] and C[B[i]+1]. The desired output is of shape (A, B). I have the following code which works, but I feel is inefficient due to index-based looping through the B axis. Is there a more efficient method?

```
import numpy as np

input_data = np.random.rand(2, 6, 10)
ind = [ 2, 3, 5, 6, 5, 4 ]

out = np.zeros( ( input_data.shape[0], input_data.shape[1] ) )

for i in range( len(ind) ):
    d = input_data[:, i, ind[i]:ind[i]+2]
    out[:, i] = np.sum(d, axis = 1)
```

Edited based on Divakar's answer:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

N = 1000

input_data = np.random.rand(10, N, 5000)
ind = ( 4999 * np.random.rand(N) ).astype(np.int)

def test_1(): # Old loop-based method
    out = np.zeros( ( input_data.shape[0], input_data.shape[1] ) )

    for i in range( len(ind) ):
        d = input_data[:, i, ind[i]:ind[i]+2]
        out[:, i] = np.sum(d, axis = 1)
    return out

def test_2(): 
    extent = 2 # Comes from 2 in "ind[i]:ind[i]+2"

    m,n,r = input_data.shape
    idx = (np.arange(n)*r + ind)[:,None] + np.arange(extent)
    out1 = input_data.reshape(m,-1)[:,idx].reshape(m,n,-1).sum(2)
    return out1

print timeit.timeit(stmt = test_1, number = 1000)
print timeit.timeit(stmt = test_2, number = 1000)

print np.all( test_1() == test_2(), keepdims = True )

>> 7.70429363482
>> 0.392034666757
>> [[ True]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) with some help from [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). We merge the last two axes of the input array, calculate the linear indices corresponding to the last two axes, perform slicing and reshape back to a 3D shape. Finally, we do summation along the last axis to get the desired output. The implementation would look something like this -

```
extent = 2 # Comes from 2 in "ind[i]:ind[i]+2"

m,n,r = input_data.shape
idx = (np.arange(n)*r + ind)[:,None] + np.arange(extent)
out1 = input_data.reshape(m,-1)[:,idx].reshape(m,n,-1).sum(2)
```

---

If the `extent` is always going to be `2` as stated in the question - `"... sum of elements C[B[i]] and C[B[i]+1]"`, then you could simply do -

```
m,n,r = input_data.shape
ind_arr = np.array(ind)
axis1_r = np.arange(n)
out2 = input_data[:,axis1_r,ind_arr] + input_data[:,axis1_r,ind_arr+1]
```

Comment: Thanks kindly! I edited the question based on your answer.

Comment: @StewartHolmes Lovely! You can also try out the second approach that assumes extent as `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [integer array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) combined with [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing):

```
import numpy as np

m,n,r = 2, 6, 10
input_data = np.arange(2*6*10).reshape(m, n, r)
ind = np.array([ 2, 3, 5, 6, 5, 4 ])
out = np.zeros( ( input_data.shape[0], input_data.shape[1] ) )
for i in range( len(ind) ):
    d = input_data[:, i, ind[i]:ind[i]+2]
    out[:, i] = np.sum(d, axis = 1)


out2 = input_data[:, np.arange(n)[:,None], np.add.outer(ind,range(2))].sum(axis=-1)
print(out2)
# array([[  5,  27,  51,  73,  91, 109],
#        [125, 147, 171, 193, 211, 229]])

assert np.allclose(out, out2)
```